# Exploding cell state in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train a multi-dimensional LSTM for image segmentation. This requires me to calculate the cell state which in the multi-dimensional case is

```
tf.tanh(cell)*input_gate 
+ cell_state_l*forget_gate_l 
+ cell_state_t*forget_gate_t
```

where all the gates x are such that 0 <= x <= 1. Now under these conditions it is not guaranteed that my cell state does not grow without bound.

What is the correct way to ensure this?

I have read several papers which use these and they do not give any indication that I need to do something extra to ensure that the cell states don't blow up. I have read papers which say to initialise the forget gates bias to a large-ish negative number which seems hacky, moreover this is not mentioned in the original work which introduced multidimensional LSTM's http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/phd.pdf

How should I control this?

Comment: Excuse me for the silly question but why don't you use the standard TF implementation of the LSTM cell? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cells_for_use_with_tensorflow_s_core_rnn_methods#LSTMCell

Comment: It doesn't have a multi dimensional cell as far as I am aware

Comment: @Ben Did you consider using a sigmoid or tanh to restrict cell state's range? e.g. `cell_state = some_computation(); cell_state = tanh(cell_state)`. Or you can simply clip it if it exceeds a specified bound. Clipping is easy to implement and might be useful

Comment: I have not. I have found https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2620 which explicitly deals with this problem. It boils down to normalising the forget_gates `tf.tanh(cell)*input_gate + (cell_state_l*forget_gate_l + cell_state_t*forget_gate_t) / (forget_gate_l + forget_gate_t)`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when learning LSTM.

This is my first look on lstm cell state calculation:

```
cell = old_cell*forget_gate + input_gate*tanh(input_state)
```

the cell  partially forgets some feature and adds up new input later, this may result in some feature to have exploding values by my intuition.

Then I found out that LSTM cell state is actually clipped by sigmoid.

```
cell = sigmoid(old_cell*forget_gate + input_gate*tanh(input_state))
```

this thus makes sure that it will not have exploding values.

pic:

[image: lstm calculation, attention on sigmoid]